# repartition.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined at file.js:1

Tags: django, chart.js

I am working on a django project and can't load chartjs.
I get the following error: repartition.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined at file.js:1

the file that has the problem is: file.js
this is the first line:

```
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = '-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
```

I have already loaded chart.js and it is working correctly on my environment.
It is loaded on index.html as follow:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Ps. working using django

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: is `file.js` loaded before chartjs is loaded?

Comment: the problem is even if I make changes to the js file, they do not appear when I reload the file and check on the inspect console